# Selenium/Python framework - import issue

Tags: python, selenium

When I run my selenium python tests via right click run in PyCharm, all is good. However, when I try to run with command line (pytest), I get error. Here is my folder structure:

```
[projectname]/
├── Driver
    ├── Driver.py
├── Tests
    ├── TestFolder
        ├── TestName.py
```

Driver.py file looks like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

Instance = None


def Initialize():
   global Instance
   Instance = webdriver.Chrome()
   Instance.implicitly_wait(2)
   return Instance


def QuitDriver():
   global Instance
   Instance.quit()
```

TestName.py looks like this:

```
import unittest
from Driver import Driver
from Tests.Transactions.HelperFunctions import *


class StreamsTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUp(cls):
        Driver.Initialize()
    
    def testSameDayEverySecond(self):
        ConnectSenderWallet()
        AppPage.HandleDevAmountsTitleAndAddress()
        HandleCreateAndAssert()
    
    @classmethod
    def tearDown(cls):
        Driver.QuitDriver()
```

And when I run  pytest -v -s Tests/TestFolder/TestName.py, I get following errors in my console:

```
    ImportError while importing test module '/Users/dusandev/Desktop/w-test/Tests/TestFolder/TestName.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
../../miniconda3/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py:127: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
Tests/TestFolder/TestName.py:2: in <module>
    from Driver import Driver
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Driver'
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: pycharm is adding the path(projectname/) when you are trying to right-click on the module name and running it.  This is the reason that it not throwing the error. Easy way to find this add this code on top of your module `import sys
print(f"The module search path is : {sys.path}")`. Now when you run from the terminal project root folder is missing in the path. So getting the error.  If you add a code to insert the folder `sys.path.insert(0,".")` then the terminal will not give you an error. Try this and let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python is trying to load the `Driver` class from `Driver.py`, however, you don't have one. You may want to do one of the following:

- Create a `Driver` class in `Driver.py`
- Replace `from Driver import Driver` with `from Driver import *`
- Replace `from Driver import Driver` with `import Driver`